# Why is e6 "forced" in this position?

Tags: theory, tactics

Larry Christiansen has played and analysed his four games against Chessmaster.

At the 8th move, he shows a different possible continuation and says that `e6` (shown below) is forced for black. I don't see why black would be any worse if another move is played, so why is this forced? For instance, is `g6` not possible?

---

```
[FEN ""]
1. Nf3 c5 2. e3 Nc6 3. c4 Nf6 4. d4 d5 5. cxd5 Nxd5 6. e4 Nf6 7. d5 Nxe4 8. dxc6 Qxd1+ 9. Kxd1 Nxf2+ 10. Ke1 Nxh1 11. Bb5 b6 12. c7+ Bd7 13. Ba6 e6
```

Comment: The only move to e6 by black is in move 13.

Comment: This continuation is not played in the game. Rather, an alternative for game's 8th move.

Comment: Christiansen uses "forced" liberally in all his videos.  I wouldn't read too much into it.  I think ...f6 followed by e5 is probably playable as well.

Answer (score 3):

White has some nasty threats involving the loose a8-rook and c7 pawn. After 13...g6:

```
[FEN ""]
[StartPly "26"]

1. Nf3 c5 2. e3 Nc6 3. c4 Nf6 4. d4 d5 5. cxd5 Nxd5 6. e4 Nf6 7. d5 Nxe4 8. dxc6 Qxd1+ 9. Kxd1 Nxf2+ 10. Ke1 Nxh1 11. Bb5 b6 12. c7+ Bd7 13. Ba6 g6 14. Bb7 Rc8 {Saving material} 15. Bf4 {Defending the passed pawn} Bg7 {Carrying on with the planned fianchetto} 16. Bxc8 Bxc8 17. Nc3 {White will be able to take the trapped h1 knight soon or even play Ra1-d1-d8#}
```

However, playing 13...e6 allows the black king to attack the c7 pawn, preventing white cramping down like this.

---

N.B. Not checked by an engine. These are just my first impressions.